# How I do change Read Time out for Zuul API gateway

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I am using Zuul API gateway wihout any service discovery, by specifying URL routes, and I am getting always the following read time out exception because my Request needs a large time to get a response.
How can i change the read time out property in application.yml ?

```
    "timestamp": 1578652198489,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException",
    "message": "Read timed out",
    "trace": "com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Read timed out
```

Answer (score 1):

From the springboot and Zuul documentation (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html#_zuul_timeouts)

> If you have configured Zuul routes by specifying URLs, you need to use ***zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis*** and ***zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis***.

In your .yml file:

```
zuul:
  host:
    connect-timeout-millis: 90000 
    socket-timeout-millis: 90000
```

Comment: Just to note; these are actually settings that go into the HttpClient (or OkHttpClient) instance that Zuul is using under the hood. It is possible to provide Zuul with a manually constructed HttpClient instance (paragraph 8.3 in the linked documentation); when you do that these configuration options have no effect anymore, you need to set the timeout values directly in the manually constructed HttpClient instance.